# How to access external protected css files of an website

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am logged in, in an website.
Assuming the website's domain is `https://example.com`.

When I was inspecting styles applicable on this website, I could see a relative path on an external css link,
like `href="/l/styles/..../app.css"`

When I append the domain name alongside like
`href="https://example.com/l/styles/.../app.css"`

and try to open on same chrome browser window where  I have logged in to the website, I can see the css files content,

but when I try to open the same link on incognito, it does not work.

I get a 404 error. HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

**I intend to somehow download the css file with the full absolute url on my Node JS server.**

I have been able to do so for multiple websites,
but I have rarely come across protected external styles route.

**How can I do the same and what url shall I use ?**

***UPDATE***

I thought styles are public mostly. Hence the confusion.
**Can styles be protected?**

**Is my assumption that styles on this website requires authorization correct ?**

Comment: When you say: it doesn't work in incognito, what exactly do you mean? What do you get?

Comment: @Mercury I get a 404 error. HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

Comment: It's certainly possible for a webserver to refuse to send any kind of content, css or otherwise to non-authenticated requests. It's also possible that there's no work around, other than being properly authenticated.

Comment: Try to login also in incognito browser, incognito considered to be a whole separate browser. And reply what you get

Comment: @Mercury after login it works though